# What is best solution for play frame by frame long animations in android?

Tags: android, eclipse, animation

i want to know What is best solution for play frame by frame long animations in android?

Thanks.

Comment: already checked AnimationDrawable?

Comment: yep!i tried that before.it have out of memory problem.

Comment: use a Handler to schedule each frame in a right time, search for Handler  sendEmptyMessageDelayed